# pthread create Error 11 on detached threads

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a server application, which waits on a queue, fetches incoming messages, and spawns a thread to process the received message and send a reply.

The pthread portion/options I am using are as follows:

```
pthread_attr_t child_attr;
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&child_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE);

// other code here

while (true)
{

    // code here to wait on valid message (msg)
    if (valid_message(msg))
    {
        pthread_t child_thread;
        MessageProcessor * processor = new MessageProcessor();
        if (0 == pthread_create(&child_thread, &child_attr, processor->process, (void *) msg))
        {
            printf("Thread dispatch successful\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error %d: could not create thread\n", errno);
        }
    }
}

// other code here
pthread_attr_destroy(&child_attr);
```

Every time I run this, the error code displayed is **11**, which *apparently* would indicate that my process has crossed the max threads threshold, based on stuff I've read on the Internet.

However,

- This is happening right from the beginning, not after I have run the application for a while.
- The threads are created detached, so I shouldn't have to use pthread_join().
- I used `top` as well as `ps -p <PID> -lfT` to check how many threads were in use by the application, and only 3 were (one for main server, one for the message receiver, and one for a message sender for the queue system)

**PS**:

The "process" prototype is as follows:

```
class MessageProcessor
{
    MessageProcessor();
    static void * MessageProcessor::process(void * arg);
}

void * MessageProcessor::process(void * arg)
{
    // do something here with arg
}
```

Comment: Assuming by "error code displayed" you actually mean "the signal that was delivered to the process", signal 11 is SIGSEGV, which is a segmentation violation, usually resulting from improper pointer usage. If 11 is actually the reported value of an `errno` variable, it's likely EAGAIN, which generally indicates a temporary failure of a call that should be retried at a later point.

Comment: @twalberg By error code displayed, I mean the error printed in my code above in the printf() - which is `errno`. A message is received every minute for 10 minutes until a valid reply is sent, and therefore the retry is happening. However, every time the message is received, the error is always 11.

Comment: Do you per chance change stack size? Do you have lots of thread-local-storage data? The EAGAIN indicated just shortage of resources, not a specific resource. The thread allocation requires: new process/thread, memory for the stack and a copy of TLS segment.

Comment: I don't change stack size, and the largest thread local data I get is usually a message or it's reply, which can be as large as 4-5 KB, but not more.

Comment: `pthread_attr_setdetachestate(&child_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE);` should be `pthread_attr_init(&child_attr); pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&child_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);` , what are you actually doing and did you initialize the `child_attr`  ? If you don't properly set the detach state to PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED, your code has a resource leak.

Comment: @nos Sorry that was a typo. It is `pthread_setdetachstate()` which takes two arguments as given in the code. I'm checking the initialisation. BRB

Comment: @nos I just checked the code. I was missing a `pthread_attr_init()`. Thank you! I added that one line and it started working. I was looking at the wrong error code I guess. Can you put your comment as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using an uninitialized `child_attr`, you'll have to do:

```
  pthread_attr_init(&child_attr); 
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&child_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
```

Answer (score 4):

Like all pthreads functions, [`pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html) does not set `errno` to report errors, it returns an error number instead. To see why it failed you need to print the return value, not `errno`.

```
const int err = pthread_create(&child_thread, &child_attr, processor->process, (void *) msg);

if (err == 0)
  printf("Thread dispatch successful\n");
else
  printf("Error %d: could not create thread\n", err);
```

POSIX specifies [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html) like so:

> The value of *errno* shall be defined only after a call to a function for which it is explicitly stated to be set [...] The value of *errno* should only be examined when it is indicated to be valid by a function's return value.

Since `pthread_create` is not documented to set `errno` it means the value is not defined after a call to `pthread_create` and should not be examined.

Comment: I think the final sentence is, strictly, too strong. Any function *might* change errno — but the value isn't meaningful unless documented to be so.

Comment: It's not *undefined*. It always has a proper value: at start it has 0 and anyone can change it later. It's defined but may not reflect the failures correctly if you don't check `errno` before & after a library/function call.

Comment: @BlueMoon, I'm quoting POSIX which says it is not defined (so I've changed from undefined to not defined, to avoid the suggestion of UB).  You should not check `errno` after a function call such as `pthread_create` which is not documented to set it, that would be meaningless. As is checking it before.

Comment: Agree, checking `errno` in pthreads is not useful. At the same time, a pthreads implementation is free to set `errno` if it desires so. But there's no requirement either way. To clarify: My previous comment about your description `errno` and not implied `errno` should be checked.

Answer (score 1):

errno 11 is usually EAGAIN, in this case it means no more processes (linux treats threads as light weight processes - see the clone manual page)available.

The `while(true)` loop will run forever making processes.

Note if you have a special version of Linux like ARM the error number 11 is NOT required to be EAGAIN.  So take this answer with a grain of salt.

Comment: The while (true) actually waits on a valid messaged to be received before proceeding (as in my code comment above), and so I know it's not creating an infinite number of threads. Plus, like I said, I checked the number of threads for that process while it was running, and there were only 3.